# C - TCP Checksum (using raw sockets) -- how to source IP address

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, checksum

When using `raw sockets` to send `TCP` data, it is allowed to leave the `source ip address` zero, so that the kernel puts in the correct value. This is helpful, especially when several interfaces (with different `IP` addresses) are in use.

My problem is now: To calculate to `TCP` checksum, I would need to know, what the source IP address is going to be in the end. This seems to be impossible to me?

Is there anyway to determine the source `IP` of my outgoing packets?

(An alternative would be, to specifically bind my raw socket to an address, but I'd rather not want to do that).

/edit: Using Linux

Comment: What OS are you using? Raw socket facilities can differ between OSes, so this is important.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the checksum?

Comment: Why not use a SOCK_STREAM socket so you don't have to worry about implementing all of TCP on your own?  I'm curious what benefit you're getting from a raw socket that makes doing all of this extra work worthwhile.

Comment: It is a research project, which enforces both `tcp` as well as using `raw sockets` and a correct checksum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't bind your socket, the kernel has to find the source address based on the destination address.

Basically a route lookup is done and a destination interface determined. After that, the IP is taken from that interface: the source for your packet.

So your question turns into performing a route lookup, the way `ip route get` does.

#### EDIT

@nos mentioned using a different socket (UDP) and connecting it to that destination address. Getting it's locally-bound name using `getsockname` should give you the source address that would be used for that destination.

Comment: You can create a UDP socket, connect() that to the same remote IP (possibly bind() it too, using INADDR_ANY) and call getsockname() on it to learn the source address. It's unlikely it'd be different than the routing of your own raw socket packets unless you have some pretty weird netfilter rules applied.

Comment: The netfilter rules aren't really that weird (fwmark), I have some in use to send mail over a different route, for example.

Comment: Even though the approach with the `UDP socket` is quite a hack, I'll probably try this one, since it seems to offer a solution to the problem. - But actually I was hoping for a nicer option ;)

Comment: @david Just bind the socket ;)

Comment: @david that is the nicest option. And tbh, RAW sockets are a hack, aren't they? ;)